# MongoDB datasource configuration in jbossas

Tags: mongodb, jboss, openshift

I am using `Openshift JBOSS` server. I would like to configure external `MongoDB` in `JBOSS`.

Is it possible to configure `MongoDB` as a datasource in `JBOSS` server ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What resources have you searched and suggestions have you found online?

Answer (score 0):

You could try taking a look at this quickstart: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/jbossas-mongoDB-quickstart.  I was able to create a JBoss application with mongodb following the instructions listed there.

If you don't want to create a new application from scratch you should be able to borrow some of the code and apply it to your application and then just add the mongodb cartridge.